# Why am I getting Unable to get header stream in saveChanges

Tags: java, spring, soap, java-8, jboss

I am trying to call a webservice from spring web mvc5 project in Jboss7.1 eap in JDK8. 
But I am getting the following error while in runtime call

```
00:07:31,206 INFO  [com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.ModelLockOutboundCmd] (default task-13) step 6 try block+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
00:07:31,490 SEVERE [com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap] (default task-13) SAAJ0539: Unable to get header stream in saveChanges
00:07:31,491 SEVERE [com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap] (default task-13) SAAJ0540: Error during saving a multipart message
00:07:31,492 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageException: Could not write message to OutputStream: Error during saving a multipart message; nested exception is co
m.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message
00:07:31,493 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.writeTo(SaajSoapMessage.java:282)
00:07:31,493 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:46)
00:07:31,493 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:658)
00:07:31,493 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:606)
00:07:31,494 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
00:07:31,494 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:506)
00:07:31,494 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:446)
00:07:31,494 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:436)
00:07:31,494 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:424)
00:07:31,495 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.ModelLockOutboundCmd.invokeWS(ModelLockOutboundCmd.java:145)
00:07:31,495 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.ModelLockOutboundCmd.updateMRFlagData(ModelLockOutboundCmd.java:132)
00:07:31,495 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.ModelLockOutboundCmd.callWs(ModelLockOutboundCmd.java:98)
00:07:31,496 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.ModelLockOutboundCmd.perform(ModelLockOutboundCmd.java:64)
00:07:31,496 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.ModelLockOutboundCmd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2ab0219b.invoke(<generated>)
00:07:31,496 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
00:07:31,496 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
00:07:31,496 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
00:07:31,497 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
00:07:31,497 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
00:07:31,497 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
00:07:31,497 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
```

I have the below jars in my lib folder of thr ear

[image]

If I add Xerces-2.9.1 and xalan-2.7.1 jar in the lib folder, I am getting a different error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Not Found [404]
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:699)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:609)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:506)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:446)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:436)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:424)
        at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.ModelLockOutboundCmd.invokeWS(ModelLockOutboundCmd.java:145)
        at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.ModelLockOutboundCmd.updateMRFlagData(ModelLockOutboundCmd.java:132)
        at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.ModelLockOutboundCmd.callWs(ModelLockOutboundCmd.java:98)
        at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.ModelLockOutboundCmd.perform(ModelLockOutboundCmd.java:64)
        at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.ModelLockOutboundCmd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2ab0219b.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
        at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.cmd.config.model.ModelLockOutboundCmd$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$678ff03a.perform(<generated>)
        at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.controller.config.model.ModelController.saveLockUnLockVersion(ModelController.java:1603)
        at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.controller.config.model.ModelController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9a0181ee.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
        at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.aspect.ExceptionAspectHandler.handleControllerExceptionsWithAroundReturnString(ExceptionAspectHandler.java:45)
        ... 68 more
```

Comment: Do you have Xalan and Xerces jar files in the path, can you post their version ?

Comment: I tried to add xalan-2.7.1.jar and xerces-2.9.1.jar in the lib folder but I am getting a different error

Comment: Can you post the error ?

Comment: ERROR [stderr] (default task-15) org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Not Found [404]
 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:699)
 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:609)
 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at org.springframework.ws.client.core

Comment: Check out this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892068/webservicetransportexception-not-found-404